# Is there a way to 'call' a image from an API in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an idea in mind. I want to get a random picture from the public archives in Flickr, Picasa and other photo-sharing sites. Is there a way, in HTML5, to do that? Yeah, I know HTML5 *isn't* quite finished yet, but I would rather not use JavaScript. And would it also be posible to have it auto-refresh after a specified amount of time?

Comment: You do not want to use JavaScript, but you tag it with JavaScript? This would require a couple of lines of serverside code, not sure why a person would want HTML to do scripting.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not for HTML5, but for a server side language. Grab the image server side (quite easy to do), display it, and have javascript refresh after a period of time. When the page refreshes, the server repeats the cycle, and all the world is at peace.

Comment: You're looking for the wrong thing. HTML is markup. It defines what's on the page, not how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

"but I would rather not use JavaScript"....then the answer is no, HTML5 alone can't do this, with JavaScript, sure some JSONP and that's cake.

HTML is a *markup language*, it's not for logic at all.  You'll need to use JavaScript for this (that's why it's there/available)...and I can't think of anything HTML5 offers that makes this any easier, it would be the same operation in JavaScript in either HTML4 or HTML5.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know if there was a specific way to get the image in HTML5 or not.